# Where I can find the source code of this kind of circle plot with x, y axis?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXCWU.png)

Image is like what shows after clicking above link

Where I can find the source code of this kind of circle plot with x, y axis?
it would be better to be realized by R
it is a visualization of keywords analysis. Pie with more frequencies gets bigger

Comment: There are no pies - just circles (pies are divided into pieces with radiuses drawn at various angles). In `ggplot2` you can easily map a column of your data to the size of a point. If you give a little bit of sample data, then we can help show you how.

Comment: in addition to what stated by Gregor you may also consider using `googleVis` package. You can do nice plots as well. In your case I guess that the "Bubble chart" section would be useful. Here's the link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html